# How do we calculate the first order energy correction with total spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, perturbation-theory

We're trying to calculate matrix elements for a perturbation theory problem. One element looks like (I've left off the $B_z$ field and some $ \hbar $ factors):

$W_{ab} = <1 1 | (1 - (S_2)^2 + (S_1)^2))S_z + (1 - (S_1)^2 + (S_2)^2)S_z |1 -1 > $
where the state $a = |sm> = |11> $ and $b = |s m> = |1 -1>$.

Okay, so then once we apply the $S_z$ operators, we just get: $S_z|sm> = \hbar m|sm>$. But I'm having a hard time understanding why we wouldn't get a zero result for $W_{ab}$ since the inner product of $<11|1-1>$ would still be zero, so it wouldn't matter what would happen once we apply the operators to the state on the right hand side: $|1-1>$.

I understand when we use raising and lowering operators for the oscillator, for example, since the states change and so we can get nonzero inner product values. What do we do with $|sm>$ states?

Comment: You have $S_1^2$ and $S_2^2$ in there so is this a 2-particle system?  Also surely there’s some typo somewhere as you can rewrite the operator as $2S_z$ since the $(1-S_2^2+S_1^2)$ and $(1-S_1^2+S_2^2)$ factors combine to $2$.

Comment: So, this is for the Hydrogen atom in a weak field. The $S_1^2$ and $S_2^2$ represent the spin of the electron and proton, respectively. Also, the perturbed Hamiltonian is: $H' = \frac{ \mu_e B_z (1 - S_2^2 + S_1^2) + \mu_p B_z (1 - S_1^2 + S_2^2)}{2 \hbar}$. I left some of the factors out the first time around but this is what it's actually like. The $S_1^2, S_2^2$ eigenvalues are $\frac{3 \hbar}{4}$